# How do I import a Postman HTTP POST into Azure Logic Apps HTTP action?

Tags: azure, http, postman

I have a `HTTP POST` set up in Postman that is working correctly. I also have an Azure Logic App that I need to invoke that `HTTP POST` instead of Postman. I see in Azure Logic Apps you can have an `HTTP POST` like so:
[image]

In Postman, it will give you the HTTP code snippet. I have tried different formats but I can't seem to get the POST to work like it does in Postman.

My Postman POST has authentication and form-data in the body which show up in the HTTP code snippet but when I paste that into the Body of the HTTP request in the logic app, the request fails.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your Authorization will probably be a bearer token which appears as a header Key vault Pair under the Key = "Authorization". Maybe if you post what your POSTMAN setup, someone can better help you.  Post the Code snippet which you are referring to as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `importer` ready to use. You need to convert whatever you have on Postman into this connector.

You should add headers (Authorization and Content Type)

Authorization: Bearer ey1230218312 (replace with valid token)

Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Body: name=abc&age=30

Comment: if you include the code snippet would be better to help you